# Clearing data in ag-grid and angular2

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying to clear ag-grid before populating data in it. Since the rowModelType is set to 'infinite', I cannot use setRowData() method to change the grid data. Instead I created another local data source which sets empty data, and then used that as the data source to my grid. I used the code below:

```
clearGrid(){
    let self = this;
    let dataSource = {
       getRows(params:any) {
          params.successCallback([],0);
       }
    };
    this.gridOptions.api.setDatasource(dataSource);
}
```

which I found itin this link:
   [Clear data in ag-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968791/cannot-call-setrowdata-unless-using-normal-row-model-error-in-ag-grid)

However when I clear the grid using clear() function above, then it looks like I cannot populate any data or at least data cannot be seen any more in the grid.

Here is my code to clear and then populate data in my component.ts:

```
public populateData(formID: string) {

    //Clear the grid first:
    this.clearGrid();

    // Create columns
    this.createColumnDefs(); 

    // Get rows from database and display them in grid:
    this.gridOptions.datasource = this.dataSource;

    // Refresh the grid:     
    this.gridOptions.api.refreshInfiniteCache();  

}
```

Everything works fine if I remove clearGrid() from the code, but then data in the grid will not be cleared, therefore old data will be there and if the number of new records will be less than the old ones, you still can see them in the grid.

I appreciate if someone can explain where I need to use this clearGrid() procedure and how to get ag-grid back to normal behavior after cleaning data in it.

Thanks a bunch for your time!

Comment: I close this question since I got the solution as I explained in the Update section.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem was. Here is my corrected version for those who might have the same issue:

```
public populateData(formID: string) {

   //Clear the grid first:
   this.clearGrid();

   // Create columns
   this.createColumnDefs(); 

   // Wrote a function that repeats all what needs to be done 
   // in order to getting the rows and display them in the grid 
   // and called it here:  
   this.populateGrid();

   // Do not refresh the grid!     
   //Also do not refresh the grid using statements like this one: 
   //this.gridOptions.api.refreshInfiniteCache();
   // It throws an error and asks for adding using setTimeout.
}
```

Comment: what needs to be done to load data in empty grid @answerd